# Content issues with multi-language store in magento2

Tags: magento2, multi-language, arabic

I want to create an **Arabic store** for my website. So I have created a store from the admin panel and applied the Smartwave Porto RTL theme.

1. Default store is showing all content but in Arabic, some blocks are missing
2. I am using the Smartwave Porto theme for the website which has multiple sub-theme like demo1 and demo2 so on. I have applied demo5 for my website but when I changed the store from English to Arabic the theme automatically changes (only on Arabic store)

3.when I changed store view to Arabic then again English then it gives an error because of the URL which becomes this after multiple switching

> http:/localhost/test?___store=default?___store=ar

4. Products name and descriptions are not converting to Arabic so how to translate these automatically

These above issues I am facing

Answer (score 0):

**Q1. Default store is showing all content but in Arabic some blocks are missing.**

Ans: May be the missing blocks doesn't exist for the Arabic store. Open those blocks in admin and save them for the Arabic stores or save them for All Store Views.

**Q2. I am using Smartwave Porto theme for website which have multiple sub theme like demo1 and demo2 so no.I have applied demo5 for my website but when i changed the store from English to Arabic the theme is automatically changes(only on Arabic store) when I changed store view to Arabic then again English then it gives an error because of the URL which becomes this after multiple switching "http:/localhost/test?___store=default?___store=ar"**

Ans: Enable the setting from back-end show the store code in the URL this should be in Store > Configuration > General.

**Q3. Products name and descriptions are not converting to Arabic so how to translate these automatically**

Ans: Add the Arabic name and Description on product details page by switching the store to Arabic in the admin. The store switcher will be on the top left corner of the product detail page in back-end.

Comment: Is it possible to translate products name and description without changing them at admin panel